# What is correct way for hotfixes?

Tags: git

I have Central (remote, origin) repo of my project at BitBucket.org. 

Cloned Live repo at my server

Cloned Dev repo at my machine

I do development on dev repo. And have pushed many commits to Central repo. But live repo is at the same state when it was cloned/initiated.

I don't want to do `git pull` on Live server until all my development stuff is done finally.

But ... I found a bug in code; which I had to fix on Live site immediately. So I went to live server (which is several commits behind central) and made a change in code. I then staged that single file and committed it.

Now when I am trying to push this commit to Central repo (so I can then pull on Dev repo), I get following:

```
# git push -u origin master
Password: 
To https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes before pushing again.  See the 'Note about
fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

I know there are questions on SO about fast-forward. But, I think I did it wrong. How can I correctly handle such a scenario? And how do I recover from it correctly now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this situation I would have created a new branch on the live version, added the fix to the new branch and then pushed the new branch to the central repo. This would then let you pull both master and the new bugfix branch onto your dev machine and deal with merge conflicts there.

```
git checkout -b bugfix
git add <fix-files>
git commit
git push origin bugfix
```

In future it might be worth keeping the live version on its own branch. That way you can control exactly what is running. If you need further fixes you can make them on the central repo (on the release branch) and just pull them on the live server.

To recover from here use

```
git checkout -b bugfix
```

to create the new branch then as Jonathon said, use

```
git branch -f master master^
```

to reset master to be in sync with the central repo

(Thanks to Jonathon for simplifying it)

Comment: That's how to avoid the problem in future, but doesn't say how to recover from the situation now (when the change is already committed to the master branch on the live server)

Comment: Thanks. What should I do when, in future I decide to bring all dev stuff on live server? The bugfix branch will still be on live. What to do with this branch? Should I merge it with master on dev?

Comment: @AsifAli, I answered that: "You can then fetch that branch on your dev machine and merge it into master cleanly and test it with the latest development version. Then when you eventually update the live server to the latest code you know that the fix will still be present."

Comment: @Trengot, why cherry-pick anything, when the fix commit is already on `master`? just branch from `master`

Comment: Create a release branch on the central repo (from master) and check that out on the live server. Keep doing dev work on master, then merge master into the release branch when you want to update it.

Comment: Got it. The fix on live will still be there in form of hotfix branch. But, after update, master itself will have that bug fixed already (from dev). So at this point, I can safely delete hotfix branch from live as well as dev and central. Right?

Comment: You don't generally need to delete branches but yes, you can merge the fix into master then just use that.

Comment: Yes, after the live server has been updated to a new version (of `master` or some release branch) that contains the fix you don't need to keep the hotfix branch

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the `master` branch on the live server and the `master` branch in the central repo have diverged.

If you don't want to do a `git pull` (and/or rebase) on the live server because that would bring other, unwanted changes then the best way to recover is create a hotfix branch on the live server, which contains your fix, then push that:

```
git checkout -b hotfix-20150127 master
git push origin hotfix-20150127
```

You can then fetch that branch on your dev machine and merge it into `master` cleanly and test it with the latest development version. Then when you eventually update the live server to the latest code you know that the fix will still be present.

You should also reset the `master` on the live server, so that its `master` is an ancestor of `origin/master` again:

```
git branch -f master master^
```

This forces git to change the head of the `master` branch to be the previous commit (before you made the fix on the live server). You won't lose the commit, because it's still on the `hotfix-20150127` branch (which is currently checked out).

The way to avoid this in future is either to create the hotfix branch *before* you start making  any changes (so the `master` branch never diverges) or create the hotfix branch on your dev machine (branching from the same revision as is on the live server) and test it there, then push it to the live server and check it out on the live server.

Basically the solution is to create a branch from the stable version running on the live server and apply essential fixes to that branch, and ensure all fixes from that branch get merged back into the main development branch. Working on two separate branches allows you to make high priority fixes to the stable version without interfering with development on the unstable branch. See [Git Flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) for a slightly more complicated but much more flexible approach.

Comment: Thanks for explaining and thanks for the Git Flow link, a long needed solution.